# Why is Arrays.equals(char[], char[]) 8 times faster than all the other versions?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, optimization

#### Short Story

Based on my tests with a few different Oracle and OpenJDK implementations, it seems that [`Arrays.equals(char[], char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-char:A-char:A-) is somehow about **8 times faster** than all the other variants for other types.

[image: Figure 1]

If the performance of your application is correlated heavily<sup>0</sup> with comparing arrays for equality, this means you pretty much want to coerce all your data into `char[]`, just to get this *magic* performance boost.

#### Long Story

Recently I was writing some high-performance code that used [`Arrays.equals(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-byte:A-byte:A-) to compare keys used to index into a structure. The keys can be quite long, and often differ only in later bytes, so the performance of this method is pretty important.

At one point I was using keys of type `char[]`, but as part of generalizing the service and to avoid some copies from underlying sources of `byte[]` and `ByteBuffer`, I changed this to `byte[]`. Suddenly<sup>2</sup>, the performance of many basic operations dropped by about 3x. I traced it down the above-mentioned fact: `Arrays.equals(char[], char[])` seems to enjoy a special status over all the other `Arrays.equals()` versions, including the one taking `short[]` which is semantically identical (and could be implemented with the identical underlying code since signedness doesn't affect the behavior of equals).

So I wrote a [JMH benchmark](https://gist.github.com/travisdowns/c7bebc4176f079ca76f3ad9dc434a776) to test all the primitive variants of `Arrays.equals(...)`<sup>1</sup> and the `char[]` variant crushes all the others, as shown above.

Now, this dominance of the ~8x variety doesn't extend at the same magnitude to smaller or much larger arrays - but it is still faster.

For small arrays, it seems that constant factors start to dominate, and for larger arrays, the L2/L3 or main memory bandwidth starts to come into play (you can already see the latter effect pretty clearly in the earlier figure, where `int[]` and especially `long[]` arrays start to degrade in performance at the large sizes). Here's a look at the same test, but with a smaller small array and larger large array:

[image: Figure 2]

Here, `char[]` is still kicking ass, just not as much as before. The per-element times for the small array (only 16 elements) are about double the standard time, probably due to function overheads: at around 0.5 ns/element, the `char[]` variant still only takes about 7.2 nanoseconds for the whole call, or about 19 cycles on my machine - so a small amount of method overhead cuts into the runtime a lot (also, the benchmark overhead itself is several cycles).

At the big end, cache and/or memory bandwidth is a driving factor - the `long[]` variant takes almost 2x as long as the `int[]` variant. The `short[]` and especially the `byte[]` variant aren't very effective (their working set still fits in the L3 in my machine).

The difference between `char[]` and all the others is extreme enough that for applications that rely on array comparison (this isn't actually that unusual for some specific domains), it's worth it to try to get all your data into `char[]` to take advantage. Huh.

What gives? Does `char` get special treatment because it underlies some `String` methods? Is it just another case of the JVM optimizing methods that are hit heavily in benchmarks, and not extending the same (obvious) optimizations to the other primitive types (especially `short` which is *identical* here)?

---

<sup>0</sup> ... and that's not even all that crazy - consider various systems which rely, for example, on (lengthy) hash comparison to check if values are equal, or hash maps where the keys are either long or variably sized.

<sup>1</sup>I didn't include  `boolean[]`, `float[]` and `double[]` or double in the results to avoid cluttering the graph, but for the record `boolean[]` and `float[]` performed the same as `int[]`, while `double[]` performed the same as `long[]`. That makes sense based on the underlying size of the types.

<sup>2</sup>I lie a bit here. The performance presumably changed suddenly but I didn't actually notice until I again ran the benchmarks, after a series of other changes, leading to a painful bisection process where I determined the causal change. This is a great reason to have some type of performance-measuring continuous integration.

Comment: Maybe it is related to char being unsigned.

Comment: @vsfDawg: You should be able to do equality comparison the same way for both signed and unsigned types.

Comment: Yeah. Bits are bits. Equals doesn't have differing signed/unsigned behavior (which is why `short[]` not getting the same treatment, since it is identical for this operation, is doubly confusing).

Comment: Serious question, I'm not being facetious: why are you writing high-performance code in Java?

Comment: @nicomp - indeed, most of us work in a world with constraints, including the language we write our software in. In fact, Java is towards the higher performance side of the spectrum (just to the slower side of C/C++) and a great deal of high performance server-side software is being written in it. In many cases, at moderate effort and expertise levels, it even outperforms lower-level langs due to well written abstractions (not always though!). Just to clarify, you've followed your argument to its conclusion and write everything to custom-run ASICs, right?

Comment: Curious if this post will follow the path of the top voted SO post...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@Marco13 guess was right. HotSpot JVM has [an intrinsic](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/812ed44725b8/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l778) (i.e. special hand-coded implementation) for`Arrays.equals(char[], char[])`, but not for other `Arrays.equals` methods.

The following JMH benchmark proves that disabling this intrinsic makes `char[]` array comparsion as slow as `short[]` array comparison.

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class ArrayEquals {
    @Param("100")
    int length;

    short[] s1, s2;
    char[] c1, c2;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        s1 = new short[length];
        s2 = new short[length];
        c1 = new char[length];
        c2 = new char[length];
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean chars() {
        return Arrays.equals(c1, c2);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(jvmArgsAppend = {"-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions", "-XX:DisableIntrinsic=_equalsC"})
    public boolean charsNoIntrinsic() {
        return Arrays.equals(c1, c2);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean shorts() {
        return Arrays.equals(s1, s2);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Benchmark                     (length)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ArrayEquals.chars                  100  avgt   10  19,012 ± 1,204  ns/op
ArrayEquals.charsNoIntrinsic       100  avgt   10  49,495 ± 0,682  ns/op
ArrayEquals.shorts                 100  avgt   10  49,566 ± 0,815  ns/op
```

This intrinsic [was added](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2008-May/000195.html) long ago in 2008 in the times of aggressive JVM competition. JDK 6 included a special `alt-string.jar` library which was enabled by `-XX:+UseStringCache`. I've found a number of calls to `Arrays.equals(char[], char[])` from one of these special classes - `StringValue.StringCache`. The intrinsic was an essential part of this "optimization". In modern JDK there is no more `alt-string.jar`, but JVM intrinsic is still there (not playing its original role though).

**Update**

I've tested the same with JDK 9-ea+148, and it appears that `_equalsC` intrinsic makes very little performance difference.

```
Benchmark                     (length)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ArrayEquals.chars                  100  avgt   10  18,931 ± 0,061  ns/op
ArrayEquals.charsNoIntrinsic       100  avgt   10  19,616 ± 0,063  ns/op
ArrayEquals.shorts                 100  avgt   10  19,753 ± 0,080  ns/op
```

`Arrays.equals` implementation has changed in JDK 9.

Now it calls [`ArraysSupport.vectorizedMismatch`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/1edd10226c97/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArraysSupport.java#l30) helper method for all types of non-object arrays. Furthermore, `vectorizedMismatch` is also a HotSpot intrinsic which has [hand-written assembly](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/00edf368e99b/src/cpu/x86/vm/macroAssembler_x86.cpp#l9328) implementation that uses AVX.

Comment: I wonder if you'd see any unexpected interactions in the benchmark if you disabled some completely unrelated intrinsic, instead of `_equalsC`.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, you may try `-XX:DisableIntrinsic=_hashCode,_getClass,_clone` etc., but they won't play role in this benchmark.

Comment: @apangin didn't jdk-9 added support for vectorization also via ArraySupport  for  Arrays equality?

Comment: One up for elaborating my guess into an answer that I'd consider as "accept"-able in every regard. I wouldn't have expected that *this* intrinsic has *such* a great impact. Instead, I would have expected the other `equals` implementations to be chewn through by the JIT, and that the result eventually would be roughly the same as the intrinsic code. But the JIT is a beast. Admittedly, I tried to locate the *actual code of the intrinsic*, but did not find it. It seems to be hidden deeply in the C1/C2 optimizer infrastructure.

Comment: @Marco13 Here is the [code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/812ed44725b8/src/cpu/x86/vm/macroAssembler_x86.cpp#l6844)

Comment: Awesome. This may also be relevant for the answer by patrickjp93. I'll add a pointer there, thanks!

Comment: @Marco13 BTW, I've just tested JDK 9-EA+148, and there is indeed almost no difference between intrinsic and non-intrinsic versions of Arrays.compare.

Comment: @apangin - does that mean that rhe JDK9 JIT can vectorize this type of code?

Comment: @BeeOnRope In fact, JDK 9 has new intrinsics for fast array comparison. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That really interesting. It looks like they added quite a few vector related intrinsics to JDK 9.

Answer (score 9):

I might go out on a limb when suggesting that this is the answer, but according to http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/9d15b81d5d1b/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l756, the `Arrays#equals(char[], char[])` method is implemented as an intrinsic.

<strike>Most likely because it is highly performance critical in all string comparisons.</strike> <- This was wrong, at least. Surprisingly, String does not use `Arrays.equals` for the comparison. But regardless of *why* it is an intrinsic, this may still be the reason for the performance difference.

Comment: Which leads to the follow-up question: What is an "intristic" in the JDK?

Comment: `String#equals` does get its own intrinsic (according to the file you linked). So your reasoning is sound.

Comment: @Thilo - an intrinsic is basically a "known function" that may be replaced with a hand-rolled assembly implementation, rather than the corresponding Java implementation (usually, the method _do_ have a bytecode implementation, but it is often never used due to intrinsification). Sometimes, the method doesn't have a java implementation at all (like `System.arraycopy` so is must be implemented as an intrinsic or native method).

Comment: You are right. `Array.equals(char[], char[])` intrinsic was added long ago in 2008. As a short [email thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2008-May/000195.html) tells, there was no immediate benefit, but there was planned some further change in JDK (that persumably never happened).

Comment: Admittedly, until now, this "answer" was rather a "guess". One might play with `PrintCompilation`, `PrintInlining` and `PrintAssembly` to verify it more thoroughly, and maybe even try *disabling* this intrinsic to be sure that it indeed *is* the reason for the higher performance. I hope that someone allocates some time for that to create an answer that is more definite (and acceptable) than this.

Comment: OK, I've added the answer supporting your initial guess. Meanwhile I've discovered the original purpose of this intrinsic.

Answer (score -4):

Because for chars, SSE3 and 4.1/4.2 are both extremely good at checking state change. The JVM-generated code for char manipulation code is more tuned because that's what Java gets used a lot for in web apps and such. Java is awful at optimizing for other kinds of data. That's just the nature of the beast.

This same behaviour is observable in Scala and GoSu as well. The bulk of information in transit these days is in text form, so unless you modify your JVM, it's tuned for text. And, as Marco mentioned, it is an intrinsic C function underneath, meaning it directly maps to high-performance vectorized instructions like SSE4.x or even AVX2 if the standard JVM has been improved that much.

http://blog.synopse.info/post/2015/06/30/Faster-String-process-using-SSE-4.2-Text-Processing-Instructions-STTNI

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/Intel-i7-nehalem-cpu,2041-7.html

Seriously, SSE4.x does not treat chars and bytes as equivalent data types, which is why text analysis is faster. Furthermore, for 8-bit integral, comparisons the instructions didn't exist until AVX2.

Comment: Why would SSE make a difference between `char`, `byte` and `short`?

Comment: For 8-bit text specifically, SSE3 and 4 have extremely advanced functions that are not as applicable to standard integral types. There's the context of UTF 8 that they use to be faster.

Comment: `char` is a 16-bit type.

Comment: Right, but it is not 8-bit text that gets a boost here, but 16-bit unsigned values. Furthermore, `equals` doesn't need any special text-related functions. It's a straight binary compare, aka `memcmp`.

Comment: Java chars aren't 8-bit, and UTF-8 isn't involved. (Even UTF-16 isn't really relevant for `Arrays.equals`, since nothing in there cares about the text interpretation of the chars.)

Comment: @BeeOnRope: It's not a straight memcmp when done in Java. Maybe that's where the boost comes from: That "intrisic" (that only the char version gets) might revert to something like memcmp.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that you can't use SSE for 8 and 16-bit integrals with anywhere near the speed you can for character types. You could just go ahead and read the intel instruction manual if you like.

Comment: @Thilo - I mean it's same type of operation as `memcmp`: a straight bitwise comparison. I didn't mean that the JVM ever uses the underlying platform/libc `memcmp` implementation - it doesn't! It's in the same vein as when people say "it's just a `memcpy`..." outside of a C/C++ context - they usually mean it's a straight copy of the underlying bits without further interpretation, regardless of whether it uses actual `memcpy` or not.

Comment: What exactly do you think a "character type" *is* to the processor, such that it would be treated differently from an equivalently-sized integer?

Comment: On x86, not an integer. Seriously, read the SSE instruction manuals for v3 and 4.1/4.2. They do not treat text as integers. And that is the secret to their performance for text analysis.

Comment: Why is my answer being downvoted?! It's correct!

The JVM maps text analysis to SSE instructions specifically tuned for text if they're available (Nehalem and later). It maps integers and floats to SSE and AVX, but using instructions that fundamentally cannot be as fast.

Comment: It is being downvoted because (1) Arrays.equals is not a text analysis function (2) your assertions about the special text analysis functions don't apply to `char` which is a 16-byte quantity - they could be applicable only to `byte`, if anything and (3) the SSE text method are never doing to my applicable for `Arrays.equals` (aka `memcmp`).

Comment: If you're talking about instructions like `PCMPISTRI`, aren't those *slower* than the packed integer comparison instructions like `PCMPEQB`?

Comment: The Nehalem text processing instructions seem overkill for a simple equality comparison. They are more for range searches, sorting, subset matching etc. https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2

Comment: It is for text. It maps directly to SSE 4.2. Seriously, do some damn research. http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/Intel-i7-nehalem-cpu,2041-7.html

Comment: No they aren't, not from a throughput perspective. They are exactly what the doctor ordered.

Comment: Bee, you are wrong 8 ways from sunday. It is a memcmp and it IS an SSE 4 optimization, even for 16-bit text. http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/Intel-i7-nehalem-cpu,2041-7.html

This is why real performance engineers don't work in Java. Your whole community has its heads buried in the sand and you don't do any due diligence. SSE 4.1/4.2 handle both 16 and 8-bit text, and they ARE the optimization used if you use **printassembly**.

Comment: [Google seems to indicate higher throughputs for packed integer equality comparisons than for the SSE4.2 string instructions.](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)

Comment: Also, if those instructions were faster, you could just *use* them for integers. Nothing's stopping you.

Comment: Can you show us PrintAssembly output demonstrating the use of SSE4.2 string processing instructions for `Arrays.equals(char[], char[])`?

Comment: Not right now as I'm in a corporate dev environment with appalling restrictions. I do know for a fact it will, because that's exactly the speedup one should expect when getting 8x the throughput per clock.

Comment: user, no you couldn't. They don't work anywhere near the same way.

Comment: Some of this discussion and guesses may become obsolete by the [link to the code that contains the actual implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/812ed44725b8/src/cpu/x86/vm/macroAssembler_x86.cpp#l6844)  that [apangin dug out in one of the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153992/why-is-arrays-equalschar-char-8-times-faster-than-all-the-other-versions/41154761?noredirect=1#comment69525810_41154761)