# How to efficiently match the namespace of an element in java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-namespaces

The `test()` function below checks if the element matches a predefined namespace `NSURI`:

```
class MyClass {
    private static final String NSURI = "http://example.com/mynamespace";

    ...

    public test(Element e) {
        return NSURI.equals(e.getNamespaceURI());
    }
}
```

Is the string comparison efficient?  I have to iterate many nodes, potentially having different namespaces. But, doing a string comparison each time seems wasteful.

Is there a faster way to do a namespace comparison?

Comment: It’s not wasteful.  And any other way of comparing namespaces is going to end up doing a String comparison anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Like VGR stated, you'll most likely encounter `String` comparisons with every method.  However, there is one option that **might** be possible.

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153992/why-is-arrays-equalschar-char-8-times-faster-than-all-the-other-versions), `Arrays#equals(char[], char[])` is intrinsic, meaning that it calls native code (or assembly) to compare arrays, making it a **much faster** alternative.  Keep in mind that JDK 9 will be released in a week from today, and this feature will be modified, but it will still ultimately be intrinsic.

Thus, if you're able to collect every namespace into a single `char[]`, it may be faster to compare them that way than to do a direct `String` comparison.

Most likely, this will end up being overkill, but it's worth a shot!